# UV unwrap displaying odd results

Tags: modeling, uv

trying to complete Blender Gurus chair tutorial, all going well till I hit the UV unwrap part. I'm getting a weird shape in the unwrap view on all parts. My google searching hasn't yielded any results
blender 2.81 on mac os 10.14.6 Mojave
im sure I have some setting wrong[image]
[image]

Comment: What unwrap method does he use in the tutorial and does he mark any seams before unwrapping? There are no seams marked on your object, but even without them selecting all on that part and choosing 'Smart UV Project' unwraps fine so I don't think there's anything wrong with your object itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a seam going across the leg, notice you get an error "unwrap failed to solve... edge seams may need to be added" in the lower right corner. Here's a pic ofn where you can add the seam highlighted in orange. You can click select one side and then ctrl click a paint on the other side to quickly select that edge. Then mark with Unwrap<Mark seam.

[image]